# MySQL update with correlated query on the same table

Tags: mysql

The problem can be simplified as follows:

Original state:

```
id   type   val
---------------
1    1      300
2    1      200
3    1      100
4    2      10
5    2      20
6    2      30
```

Desired state - for a range of `id`s (here 3 to 4), update `val` so that it's equal to the maximum `val` for the given `type`:

```
id   type   val
---------------
1    1      300
2    1      200
3    1      300  <--
4    2      30   <--
5    2      20
6    2      30
```

So only rows 3 and 4 were updated, maximum `val` for `type` 1 is 300, for `type` 2 it's 30.

I thought it's an easy update, but I can't get it to work.

Here's the table definition and data:

```
create table test (id integer primary key, type integer, val integer);
insert into test (id, type, val) values (1, 1, 300);
insert into test (id, type, val) values (2, 1, 200);
insert into test (id, type, val) values (3, 1, 100);
insert into test (id, type, val) values (4, 2, 10);
insert into test (id, type, val) values (5, 2, 20);
insert into test (id, type, val) values (6, 2, 30);
```

And here's what I thought would work:

```
update test t1 set t1.val=(
  select max(t2.val) from (
    select * from test where type=t1.type
  ) t2
) where id>=3 and id<5;
```

However MySQL gives the error:

> Unknown column 't1.type' in 'where clause'

I've found some answers to similar problems suggesting rewriting the update so that it uses JOIN, but I'm not sure how to do that - my attempt resulted in an error message about a nonexisting table. Please tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: one solution is using SELECT INTO (using var)

Comment: @Ashutosh I'm not sure how I would use it, could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE test t1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT TYPE,MAX(val) mval FROM test GROUP BY TYPE) t2
ON t1.type=t2.type
SET t1.val=t2.mval
WHERE t1.id BETWEEN 3 AND 4;
```

Fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Sn9aDBPze7pVvHNHFzQ1u/2

Comment: Glad I could help @husakg

Answer (score 0):

To answer your quesetion, you need to select only val from inner sub-query. 
This works:

```
UPDATE test1 t1 
SET 
    t1.val = (SELECT 
            MAX(t2.val)
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                val
            FROM
                test1
            WHERE
                type = t1.type) t2)
WHERE
    id >= 3 AND id < 5;
```

Comment: Here I have table name as "test1"

Comment: This is still giving me the same error: Unknown column 't1.type' in 'where clause' (trying in SQL Fiddle)

Comment: I run it in my local mysql workbench. So this might work.Let me try in sql fiddle